# PHP cookie gets deleted on page change?

Tags: php, cookies

I looked around and I couldn't find a working answer, so I'll ask here.

I have this code:

```
setcookie('cookie1',"121",strtotime( '+30 days' ),"/");
```

When I set it and read it on the same page with

```
echo $_COOKIE['cookie1']
```

It reads fine, but when I click a link on that page and go to another page, the cookie doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: what if you add a last param as `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` in `setcookie()` ?

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073304/cookie-not-saving

Comment: great !! it worked for u .. let me add as answer so that it helps other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem could be solved by adding the domain name at the end

```
setcookie('cookie1',"121",strtotime( '+30 days' ),"/",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

> The domain that the cookie is available to. Setting the domain to
>   'www.example.com' will make the cookie available in the www subdomain
>   and higher subdomains. Cookies available to a lower domain, such as
>   'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as
>   'www.example.com'. Older browsers still implementing the deprecated »
>   RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
setcookie('cookie1',"121",time()+2592000,"/");//30 days equals 2592000 seconds
```

Comment: time()+2592000 is the same as strtotime( '+30 days' )

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your own browser is storing cookies?
take a look to your browset privacy settings.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. I have a cookie checker that shows the cookies, but when I go to the next page, it gets deleted. The same thing is going on with `$_SESSION` variables. They don't get transferred to the next page. What could cause that?